# Recursive array from structure with only childids

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion

I have a structure like this

```
$list = array(
  array('code'=>1,'children'=>array(2,3),'name'=>'number one'),
  array('code'=>2,'children'=>array(4),'name'=>'number two'),
  array('code'=>3,'children'=>array(5,6),'name'=>'number three'),
  array('code'=>4,'children'=>array(7),'name'=>'number four'),
  array('code'=>5,'children'=>array(),'name'=>'number five'),
  array('code'=>6,'children'=>array(8),'name'=>'number six'),
  array('code'=>7,'children'=>array(),'name'=>'number seven'),
  array('code'=>8,'children'=>array(),'name'=>'number eight')
);
```

and I need the return to be

```
array(
  array('code'=>1,'children'=>array(
    array('code'=>2,'children'=>array(
      array('code'=>4,'children'=>array(7),'name'=>'number four'),
    ),'name'=>'number two'),
    array('code'=>3,'children'=>array(
       array('code'=>5,'children'=>array(),'name'=>'number five'),
       array('code'=>6,'children'=>array(
          array('code'=>8,'children'=>array(),'name'=>'number eight')
       ),'name'=>'number six'),
    ),'name'=>'number three'),
  ),'name'=>'number one')
);
```

Note that I don't have a parent id, only children id. and the id isn't a key (although I can make a foreach and make a key from it). Any ideas on how I can make this with minimal passages?

Comment: We are not a code writing service here! Did you tried something ?

Comment: This is not the right attitude...

Comment: and got downvoted so the chances to actually get help are pretty much done. oh well. maybe I'll answer my own question in the future

Comment: @Ricardo I think people here can be a little too quick to assume lack of effort. While there are a lot of "code plz!" questions, this does not seem to be one. This is especially a problem for those tagged with 'algorithm', as they tend to be at the point before any code has been written!

Comment: Still, it could be helpful to give it a try. One often learns more from experimentation than from someone else offering a solution.

Comment: And I do have to apologize about been rush to answer as well @gilleain

Comment: The goal for this is to serve a json structure through a Restfull API to a javascript interface. Some of the children nodes will have multiple parents so I am doing several passes through the initial list. The first will index the array for id (instead of a numeric index) and the following will fill a "parent" property with an array of ids. I think I can produce a decent enough json for the frontend. On that. I have to go with D3 or something that allows to create a complex interface. Again, I do apologize for being blunt on my answer. Under a lot of pressure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
//2 pass:

//#1 add keys, objectify
$output = array();
foreach ($list as $k => $el) {
    $output[$k + 1] = (object) $el;
}

//#2 build
foreach($output as $k=>$el) {
    if (!empty($el->children)) {
        $children=$el->children;
        $output[$k]->children=array();
        foreach($children as $childID) {
            $output[$k]->children[]=$output[$childID];
        }
    } else {
        //remove it, no child nodes
        unset($output[$k]->children);
    }
}
```

so, `$output[1]` has our tree, and the rest of `$output` can be discarded since it is essentially just extra references to the nodes attached to `1`.

```
$tree=$output[1];

print_r($tree);
stdClass Object
(
    [code] => 1
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 2
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [code] => 4
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [code] => 7
                                                    [name] => number seven
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [name] => number four
                                )

                        )

                    [name] => number two
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 3
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [code] => 5
                                    [name] => number five
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [code] => 6
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [code] => 8
                                                    [name] => number eight
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [name] => number six
                                )

                        )

                    [name] => number three
                )

        )

    [name] => number one
)
```

my structure differs slightly than yours since I used objects, which are better suited to this in that they are accessed by reference, which is what you want when dealing with nodes. And if this is `JSON` it will likely become an object anyway.

Comment: Great mate! using objs and only reference them I can affect them and have all the references updated without mucking around again. This fit the bill with some adjustments. Really good. Thank you for this